# Удаление строки из mysql и html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Нужно реализовать удаление созданной ранее строки, взятой из бд и выведенной на экран.
Всё работает, но для удаления строки со страницы - необходимо перезагрузить страницу. Мне нужно, чтобы удаление происходило стразу при нажатии на кнопку.

Подскажите, как реализовать?

```
    function adding(){
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `words`");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['word']."</td>"."<td style='color:#4b99cf'><a name='del' href='index.php?del=".$row["number"]."'>x</a></td>"."<td>".$row['translate']."</td></tr>";
        }
        if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
           $del = intval($_GET['del']);
           $query = "delete from `words` where (number='$del')";
           /* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
           mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно сначала удалить, а потом вывести результат. Потому-что сейчас вы выводите всё строки до удаления, и только потом удаляете. А вам же не нужно выводить то, что удаляете.

```
function adding() {
   if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
       $del = intval($_GET['del']);
       $query = "delete from `words` where (number='$del')";
       /* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
       mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `words`");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['word']."</td>"."<td style='color:#4b99cf'><a name='del' href='index.php?del=".$row["number"]."'>x</a></td>"."<td>".$row['translate']."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Так же рекомендую удалять через AJAX, а не переходом по ссылке.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно сначала вывести всё на страницу, иначе не будет кнопки, которая так-же выводится на страницу, после нажатия на которую, должна удалиться только та строка, с которой создана именно эта ссылка.

Comment: Так всё и будет выводиться. Оно не будет только выводить то что удалили. Вы сначала проверьте код, а потом уже коментируйте .

Comment: Прошу прощения, всё понял, реализовал. Спасибо за помощь.